# Fail an AWS Lambda in Java Without Exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

If an unhandled exception escapes an AWS Java Lambda it will be treated as an error for that lambda. The node.js version of AWS Lambda seem to have a way to call context.fail() to signal that the AWS Lambda was not successful but without have an exception escape.

Is there something similar for the Java version of AWS Lambda?

It seems that unhandled exceptions that escape an AWS Lambda in Java not only mark the invocation as an error but also destroys that Lambda so that a new cold lambda is needed to replace it. I'd like to have the Lambda fail without being destroyed by the unhandled exception.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using a state machine? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-creating-lambda-state-machine.html

Comment: I am aware of Step Functions and the additional error handling they can do outside of the Lambda itself but within the State Machine still, but am currently looking for a pure Lambda way to accomplish this, if it's possible.

Thanks for suggesting an alternate option though.

Comment: Throwing an exception doesn't destroy the lambda instance and invocations soon after can reuse the instance that errored.

Comment: Ah, I learned that some time after making this post. Not sure how I got it in my head that that was the case. Clearly it was long enough after this question to have forgotten that I had put this incorrect information out there. If you'd like to say that in an Answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer so no one else gets confused like I was.

Comment: won't the blanket Exception block handle all the exceptions ?